# Can we say $x=4$ is a Point of Inflexion

Tags: calculus, functions

I have doubt that can we say the graph of $y=(x-4)^{\frac{3}{7}}$ has point of inflexion at $x=4$. Because even though $f''(4) \ne 0$, there is change of concavity to convexity at $x=4$

Comment: Are you sure the sign of the second derivative changes?

Answer (score 1):

The graph of $y=(x-4)^{\frac{3}{7}}$ has point of inflexion at $x=4$. Because there is change of concavity to convexity at $x=4$. As $f''(x)$ is not defined at 4, the question of inflexion remains open. The sufficient existence condition requires  $f′′(x+ε)$ and $ f′′(x-ε)$ to have opposite signs in the neighborhood($ε$) of x (Bronshtein and Semendyayev 2004)